# Extract details that are in both using awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a script which needs to extract details that exist on both versions.

```
ABC-A1   1.0  tomcat                
BBC-A1   2.0  tomcat                           
CAD-A1   1.0  tomcat        
ABC-A1   2.0  tomcat           
BBC-A1   2.0  tomcat
```

In the above data , I would like to extract the names that exist in both 1.0 and 2.0 ( that will be `ABC-A1` and `BBC-A1` )

How can I do this using *awk or sed* or any other?

Comment: Have you try'd any code yourself yet?

Comment: As per your requested question `sed -n 's/^\([AB][B][C]\)/\1/p' /tmp/file`

Comment: `BBC-A1` only has 1 version.

Answer (score 3):

Given that input file all you need is:

```
$ awk 'c[$1]++{print $1}' file
ABC-A1
BBC-A1
```

If that's not adequate for your real input, update your question to show some input/output that's more truly representative of your real problem.

Per @jaypals comment below, if you really DO need to check the version number too then modify it to:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1,$2]++ && cnt[$1]++ {print $1}' file
ABC-A1
```

Note that this only prints one output since in the posted sample input BBC-A1 was actually specified with the same version number twice.

Comment: Isn't `awk 'a[$1]++ && !a[$1,$2]++ { print $1 }'` more apt for what OP wants? I do agree a better data set would have been helpful! `:)`

Comment: I always try to provide the simplest solution first and let the OP fix his input data if it's not adequate to demonstrate his problem. This might be just fine and if not then it'll get the OP thinking about his real problem and maybe there's other things he forgot to tell us about and/or show in his example.

Comment: @jaypalsingh I added your example. Figure it might save time :-). Had to change the order of evaluation of the conditions so the seen is ALWAYS updated regardless of the cnt

Comment: Thanks @Ed. Yeah, I messed up on the ordering. Didn't test it just went with my train of thought which tells me isn't trust worthy! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

This works for the text format specified and only versions 1.0  and 2.0

```
n=0
while IFS=$' \t' read module version tomcat; do
        if echo ${modulesv1[@]} | tr -t ' ' '\n' | grep -q ^$module$ ||
           echo ${modulesv2[@]} | tr -t ' ' '\n' | grep -q ^$module$ ; then
                echo $module has versions 1.0 and 2.0
        fi
        if [[ $version =~ ^1.0$ ]]; then
                modulesv1[$n]=$module
        elif [[ $version =~ ^2.0$ ]]; then
                modulesv2[$n]=$module
        fi
        let n=++n
done < file_with_modules_and_versions
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk:

```
awk '
    {names[$1]=1; ver[$1,$2]=1} 
    END {for (n in names) if (ver[n,"1.0"] && ver[n,"2.0"]) print n}
' file
```

---

This pipeline will output names with at least 2 different versions (not specifically "1.0" and "2.0")

```
awk '{print $1, $2}' file | sort -u | awk '++seen[$1] == 2 {print $1}'
```

Comment: glenn Jackman ,  The snippet works exactly as needed. Though i have written a Script in shell which will take every name and compare with others. The task is done but this will help me in Future.                                   Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
awk '{a[$1];seen[$1,$2]=1}END{for(i in a)if(seen[i,"1.0"]&&seen[i,"2.0"])print i}' file
```

Keys are set in the array `a` for all values in the first column. The combination of the first and second column are used to set a value in `seen`. Names that have a "1.0" and a "2.0" entry in `seen` are printed once the file has been processed.

Note that in your example, you have defined `BBC-A1 2.0` twice, so the output of the script is just `ABC-A1`.